# Rendering fine detail when plotting Fractal sets MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, rendering, resolution, fractals

I'm trying to analyse the area of a self-similar set in MATLAB. The full image is shown on the LHS below. When zooming in, one can see that MATLAB only renders the image to the scale shown in the centre image. On the RHS below is the resolution when I zoom in on the Matlab figure rather than the printed bitmap - it shows this detail that I want to render, but is not rendered when I print the figure.

[image: Comparison of images]

I've made the plot with the *viscircles* function. As a side note, **I'd also like to fill in the circles**.

I'm using *print* to save save the plot as a bitmap. I've tried:

1. Increasing the resolution of the file I'm saving with *print*, but that doesn't appear to render the image in more detail but merely save the resolution-limited image with more pixels.
2. Increasing the size of the figure on the screen in the hope of trying to make it render the whole thing. I can't seem to make the image bigger than my monitor. Would suppressing the output of the image help?
3. A different approach: taking the coordinates that I was passing to *viscircles* and then drawing circles around them without using a MATLAB plot function. This required a loop for the 10^6 particles in my simulation and was very slow whereas the *viscircles* approach only took a day - I think it does plot all circles at once.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`scatter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html?s_tid=doc_ta)? This should be much more convenient the `viscircles`, and you can set the inner color easily.

Comment: You can save the figure in a vector format so you don't have resolution issues. Or, you can try to use [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)

Comment: EBH: I started with scatter but you can't control the radius of the circles it plots: it is fixed to some function of the scale at which the whole image is rendered

Comment: I believe my analysis requires a bitmap as I'm trying to evaluate the area of pattern. I need that bitmap to be rendered at a sufficient resolution so that I can accurately evaluate the area.

Comment: In the image above it looks like all circles have the same size. Anyway, you can control the size of the circle with `scatter`, [take a look at this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html?s_tid=doc_ta#btrli6o-1). Regarding area measurements, if you know all circles radii (because you use `viscircles`) then you know all circles area, thus all you need is to count the circles in the area of interest (if they are indeed of equal size) or sum the area of all circles in it.

Comment: @EBH: I'm not sure using scatter would've solved my resolution in rendering  problems, but your approach in which I count the circles is very helpful and should sort this out for me.